# Android using localhost

Tags: android

I have the following URL

```
mvc.local/users/login
```

For this i have the following Android code:

```
public String sendToServer(List<NameValuePair> pair, String url){
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
    try {
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(pair));
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        if (response != null) {
            InputStream ips  = response.getEntity().getContent();
            BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ips,"UTF-8"));
            if(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()!=HttpStatus.SC_OK)
            {
                try {
                    throw new Exception(response.getStatusLine().getReasonPhrase());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String s;
            while(true)
            {
                s = buf.readLine();
                if(s==null || s.length()==0)
                    break;
                sb.append(s);

            }
            buf.close();
            ips.close();
            return sb.toString();
        }

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "Error";
}
```

However i get the following error:

```
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Target host must not be null, or set in parameters. scheme=null, host=null, path=
```

So my question is how do i use the localhost?

Comment: Are you trying this on a simulator or on a physical device?

Comment: I am using a simulator

Comment: Maybe this might help: http://developer.android.com/guide/faq/commontasks.html#localhostalias

Comment: @NKN What if the localhost im using is the one called mvc.local (as you can see)

Comment: Using: 10.0.2.2/users/login doesn't work?

Comment: Have you preceded the host with `http://`? So it would finally be: `http://10.0.2.2/users/login`

Comment: @NKN My current is:         HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://mvc.local/users/remote_login");

Comment: Try changing it by: `HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/users/remote_login");`

Comment: I have to use mvc.local because im using a virtual host